# funcall/apply lambda

Tags: functions, apply, funcall

Please look at the following elisp expressions.

```el
(funcall 'lambda '() 1)
;; or
(apply 'lambda '() 1 ())
```

The interpreter says that lambda is not a valid function for both the above expressions. Why? Is it because `lambda` is a macro? If so, is there a variant of `funcall/apply` for macros?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Drew, understood. I mistook the number of watchers with the number of posts for each tag and was wondering why they were few.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `lambda` is a macro. There is a function that is like `funcall` for macros called `eval`.

Comment: Isn't there one for `apply`? Or a way to convert a list into its elements, prefereably without evaluating them?

Comment: No, `eval` is not split into two variants like `funcall` and `apply`. I have no idea what you mean about converting a list to it's elements; if you want to access the elements of a list you can use `nth` or, `car` and `cdr`. Perhaps you need to ask a better question, one that is focused on what you actually want to accomplish instead of random primitive operations. For more information about primitives, you can open the Elisp manual inside Emacs with `C-h i`.

Comment: Alright, thanks for reply. Maybe we can chat.